# Android Device Monitorが起動しない

Tags: android-studio

Android Studioを導入して、自分のスマホが認識できるか確認しようと
Android Device Monitorを起動させてみると、以下のログが吐き出されてしまい起動できません。

同様の事例がないかググってみると、

1. 管理者権限でAndoroid Studioを起動する
2. ユーザー名に空欄があると起動しない

という事例は見つけておりますが、残念ながらどちらを実施しても起動しませんでした。

的はずれな内容かもしれないのですが、よろしくお願いいたします。

＜使用しているもの＞
・Windows10 pro
・Andoroid Studio 3.0.1

＜以下、ログの一部だけ＞

```
!SESSION 2018-02-01 11:09:16.245 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=9.0.4
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=ja_JP
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -data @noDefault

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2018-02-01 11:09:16.927
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.apache.ant_1.8.3.v201301120609/@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2018-02-01 11:09:17.102
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.apache.jasper.glassfish_2.2.2.v201205150955.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2018-02-01 11:09:17.118
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.apache.lucene.core_2.9.1.v201101211721.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2018-02-01 11:09:20.792
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.eclipse.help.base_3.6.101.v201302041200.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2018-02-01 11:09:20.796
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.eclipse.help.ui_3.5.201.v20130108-092756.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2018-02-01 11:09:20.801
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.eclipse.help.webapp_3.6.101.v20130116-182509.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2018-02-01 11:09:20.900
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.eclipse.jetty.server_8.1.3.v20120522.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2018-02-01 11:09:21.127
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.eclipse.platform.doc.user_4.2.2.v20130121-200410.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2018-02-01 11:09:21.205
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.eclipse.team.core_3.6.100.v20120524-0627.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2018-02-01 11:09:21.215
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.eclipse.team.ui_3.6.201.v20130125-135424.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2018-02-01 11:09:21.235
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.eclipse.ui.cheatsheets_3.4.200.v20120521-2344.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2018-02-01 11:09:21.275
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.eclipse.ui.intro_3.4.200.v20120521-2344.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.runtime 4 0 2018-02-01 11:09:21.826
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The bundle "org.eclipse.core.runtime_3.8.0.v20120912-155025 [46]" could not be resolved. Reason: Missing Constraint: Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: CDC-1.0/Foundation-1.0,J2SE-1.3
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.getResolverError(AbstractBundle.java:1332)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.getResolutionFailureException(AbstractBundle.java:1316)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:323)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1176)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
```

Answer (score 3):

同じ現象で困ってました。JDK9をいれてましたが、JDK8をインストールしてから、起動しました。現状AndoroidStudio3では、JDK9では対応できないということだと思います。

Comment: 関連?: [Does Android Studio 3 support Java 9 for Android development?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47627499/5989200) -- Stack Overflow